# Android WebView - Programmatically forcing numeric keyboard on 3rd party webpage's input field?

Tags: android, html, webview, user-input, android-softkeyboard

**Quick context:** We have a pretty unique situation where we're switching to a new HR platform which will only allow our factory employees to timekeep via a timeclock webpage. We already have several Samsung Galaxy Tab A devices positioned throughout our building that serve as timeclock kiosks for the current HR system. Since we can only lock these tablets down to a single app at a time via Knox, a Chrome web browser for example would let employees accidentally navigate off the new platform's timeclock webpage and create issues for others trying to clock-in or out.

*SO*, we already setup an Android app that implements a basic WebView hard-coded to the timeclock URL the new HR company provided us. *HOWEVER*, the big problem here is that there's no on-page keyboard and the badge ID field is of type **text**, which invokes the Android qwerty keyboard for a badge ID PIN that would only ever be all numbers... A 3rd-party company built this webpage for the HR company so I'd be surprised if we could ever get it changed on their end.
[image: Our custom Android app with WebView emulated side-by-side with the dev tools panel on the same site.]

---

Just to show some of our basic boilerplate to achieve the above...

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Paytime Time Clock"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PaytimeWebpage"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private WebView webView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            webView.setInitialScale(300);
            webView.loadUrl("https://site.time.clock");

            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        }
    }
```

**Activity_Main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

We've done tons of exhaustive searching and really tried to think outside the box here but as only 2 SysAdmins at a small manufacturer we are by no means seasoned Java devs! We've tried researching and attempting the following ideas:

- Event listener for whenever the qwerty keyboard is invoked to then instead invoke the numeric or telephone keyboard
- Get HTML content from WebView, look for the `<input type="text">` tag and try to programmatically change it to either `number` or `tel` in order to get the right keyboard to show
- Force our app to invoke the numeric keyboard and strictly keep it there above the web page
- We've seen guys mentioning the [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) class for configuring input and keyboard types, but the problem with that is of course that we're not handling the input in question here within our app, it's on someone else's webpage through our WebView

This is of course a very minor edge-case issue that we're forced to come up with a complicated solution to ourselves... We can observe [which input types yield which keyboards](https://inputtypes.com/) on any Android device. All we have to do is get a numeric soft-keyboard shown on this WebView'd site within our app such that employees can easily walk up, input their badge and complete their clock action.

I hope this was concise but thorough... There must be a creative solution here, does anybody have any suggestions or recommendations of how we can accomplish this? Even just pointing us in the right direction would be hugely appreciated... THANKS!!

Comment: What about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28845319/15298643)

Comment: Also you could [trigger focus on a text input field in a WebView after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27871439/15298643)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your WebViewClient, override `onPageFinished()` and do the following in it:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('FldBadge').getElementsByTagName('input')[0].type='number';");
```

The idea is to modify the loaded page so that it behaves the way you need.

UPDATE: Full code

```
        public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
          public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url) {
            if(url.equals("https://my.website.url")) {     
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('FldBadge').getElementByTagName('input')[0].type='number';");
            }
          }
        }
```

Don't forget to change the URL in the code to your own.

In the activity's onCreate:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

Comment: This is great, on a PC we can input that javascript into the console and see that it changes the badge input field to the desired input type! However when we run this within the app it seems to make the whole webpage show the console output, which is just **'number'** being displayed as text and no other content. We're currently trying to figure out how to suppress the console output taking over the whole page!

Comment: By default, the console output does not go onto the screen in WebView, so you are seeing something  other than console output. Please note that for the code to work in a WebView, you need to put it inside onPageFinished() of your own class derived from WebViewClient. It is also desirable to check the URL in that method to make sure the changes are being made on the right page.

Comment: That worked great! Thanks a ton! Also adding a void fixed the [input type taking over the page](https://imgur.com/a/ysgzziS) issue. Final code along with an input focus add-on:
`webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('FldBadge').getElementsByTagName('input')[0].type='number';void(0);");
webView.requestFocus(view.FOCUS_DOWN);
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('FldBadge').getElementsByTagName('input')[0].click().focus();");`